# Calling nested R script from python using rpy2

Tags: python, r, nested, rpy2

I have 2 separate R scripts such as func1.R and func2.R. Both are functions which receive inputs and return outputs e.g., func1(a,b) and func2(c,d). But, func2.R is being called to compute something inside func1.R as follows:

```
func1<-function(a,b){
 compute c and d here somehow
 e <- func2(c,d)
 return e
}
```

For calling a single R script like func3.R with no nested call:

```
func3<-function(a,b){     
  e <- a + b
  return e
}
```

the following Python works:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects    
def func3(a,b):
    path = 'path_to/R_files/'
    ro=robjects.r        
    ro.source(path+"func3.R")    
    return ro.func3(robjects.FloatVector(a),robjects.FloatVector(b))
```

What would be the Python code to use func1.R and func2.R?

Comment: Are functions 1 and 2 and 3 on different R scripts or on the same R script?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Inside different R files, func1.R, func2.R, and func3.R. func3.R is not part of question BTW. Suppose that I have 2 R scripts, one is called inside the other.

Comment: Since they are in different Rscripts, you should only load the last Rscript that sources the other Rscripts.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Inside different R files, func1.R, func2.R, and func3.R. func3.R is not part of question BTW. There is no problem with calling func3.R stand alone in python, because there is no call inside that and I provided the python code. Suppose that I have 2 R scripts, e.g., func1.R and func2.R, func2.R is called inside the func1.R.

Comment: I do get your point. Just ensure that the first line of func2.R script sources func1.R script, then only source func2.R into python the way you just showed

Comment: Here is the Python error: RRuntimeError: Error in func2(sample = c, location = d) : 
  could not find function "func2"

Comment: How ensure that the first line of func2.R script sources func1.R script? Could you  provide sample code?

Comment: It seems you are sourcing func1 and not func2. I will help you out:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `func1.R` script:

```
#define function1 here:
func1 <- function(c, d){
 }
```

Your `func2.R` script:

```
#define function 2 that uses function1

source("func1.R")
func2 <- function(a,b){
 compute c and d here somehow
 e <- func2(c,d)
 return e
}
```

Your python code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects    
def func3(a , b):
    path = 'path_to/R_files/'
    ro = robjects.r        
    ro.source(path + "func2.R")    
    return ro.func3(robjects.FloatVector(a),robjects.FloatVector(b))
```